# How to get the correlation coefficients for each row in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, scipy

I'm trying to correlate population data and human right scores but I've looked to many articles and did not find the answer I intended.

[image]
This is the data set I'm working with and I will be needing each correlation value for each row.

Comment: Try df.corr ...?

Comment: I'll be wanting it for each row though

Comment: Are you sure you want it for each row ? In case you want it for a group of rows, you could take a look at rolling.corr - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.corr.html

Comment: yes I want it for each row because I'll be wanting all the correlations for each country and there human right score

Comment: So it should be like x = 2017 and y = human right score but for all the dataframe rows

Comment: "wanting it for each row" I am afraid is not statistically correct. You can either do it for all with df.corr, or as @Sajan said, do it with some group of rows

Comment: It is impossible to count correlation for two values.

Comment: so I cant apply scipy stats function for x and y value for each row for getting slope, intercept, r_value, p_value for my plot

Comment: @SiddharthPilli I think you might mix up the definition of column and row? Think about that, if you do it for each row you only get 1 single x(population) and 1 single y (human right score), which translate to 1 single point on your plot...

Answer (score 0):

everybody I did a bit of research and added few more features to my dataset now everything works as intended.